# How can I run Javascript without a browser or node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, es6-class

I want to create a Javascript app but I want to do that only using Javascript.
Because the node js is framework and I don't want to use any framework,
can I create a Javascript app without a browser and without any framework?

Only using Javascript?

Comment: Nodejs is not a framework. A browser is not a framework. JavaScript requires a runtime engine, that is what they are.

Comment: You need a javascript shell. Node.js is the major one and it’s not a framework, you can do with it what you like, it’s simply a runtime environment

Comment: No. If you want to make an app i would consider using electron

Comment: @ptothep electron is a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a javascript application, you need a javascript runtime, in the end you will have to install some, however, you can try something different like live-server from npm

Answer (score 0):

You could install nodejs runtime environment and run your code in cmd explained here. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-do-you-run-javascript-script-through-the-terminal/#:~:text=You%20can%20Run%20your%20JavaScript,Environment%20Download%20and%20Download%20it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-do-you-run-javascript-script-through-the-terminal/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20Run%20your%20JavaScript,Environment%20Download%20and%20Download%20it).

Answer (score 0):

Node js is actually not a framework or a library, but a runtime environment, based on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. I suggest you use it.
Just install, type in console(powershell, bash, etc.):
`node file.js` 
and I will run your app.